# How can I transfer information from an Android app to a Ni myRio embedded hardware device

Tags: android, embedded, microcontroller

I am trying to transfer instructions from an Android app to a Ni myRio embedded hardware device.
I can't seem to find any documentation.

Comment: The Ni myRio has a built in WIFI. Did you get a look on this side ?

Comment: which communication interfaces to your RIO are you comfortable/proven working with?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with this:

**Android**

- Run your Android application in the IDE's built-in Android Mobile Device Emulator.

  Have it stream 'Hello World' via UDP to some port on localhost (say, 1234)

**LabVIEW RIO**

- Run your RIO application against the LabVIEW FPGA Emulator (right-click your FPGA target in project explorer and select 'run on -> emulator')

  Have it listen to 1234 on localhost, and print the output to a simple String Buffer that displays on the VI's front panel*1

Both of these have readily searchable tutorials*2, and remove HW from the equation, so you should be able to complete them successfully, and then iterate past to a final solution (WiFi?). If you get it working on real HW, consider posting a (brief) followup-answer to your question here.

-Justin

*1: Don't do this front-panel debug-hack in the deployed fpga code!

*2: Check NI's Example Finder for the LabVIEW FPGA UDP tutorials.